# Angular2 display data with template based on routing

Tags: angular, service, routes

I am trying to create a page with images that are linked to another template. Then within that template I will display data based on which image the user clicked.

For example, it's a companies portfolio site, there is a work page with just images, when the user clicks on an image (project) it should load a new template and using interpolation display the data for that project, i.e: project title, description, more images etc.

This would save me making separate pages for each project, I've researched for about 3 days to find a solution and I think I should be using a service.

I just can't figure out how to route the image to load specific data for that project in the new template.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a component with input data :

```
@Component({
selector: 'poject-data',
template: '...',
})
export class ProjectDataComponent {
  private contentUrl: SafeResourceUrl;
  @Input() project: Project;
  ...
}
```

And use it in your main component with something like :

```
<project-data project="selectedProject" *ngIf="selectedProject != null"></project-data>
```

Where "selectedProject" is a field of your main component that change on click.